# How to declare Ropes in Java?

Tags: string, ropes

What are `ropes` in Java?

How can you initialize them in Java as the replacement for `Strings` in Java?

*Why was this concept introduced?*

Comment: @babu : there is no proper explanation found in google

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ropes/index.html look into this may be this is enough for u

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I could explain it better than [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ropes/index.html), especially down [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ropes/index.html#N1014A), if I wanted to. Hope this helps.